# Load src content to SVG image dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have a SVG <image> rendered in the browser. I would like to change its content dynamically as attempted on http://jsfiddle.net/dt1510/pXA9P/1/ . In console.debug the content is changed, however in the browser it is the same.

```xml
<svg>  
  <image x="20" y="20" width="300" height="80"
     xlink:href="http://www.erh.noaa.gov/ilm/OpenLayers/img/marker.png" />    
</svg>​
```

```js
var srcAirline = "data:image/png;base64,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";

$('document').ready(change_image);

function change_image(){    
    var images = $("image");
    var image = images[0];        
    $(image).removeAttr("xlink:href");
    $(image).attr("src", srcAirline);
    console.debug(image);
}
```

I read somewhere that it might be possible with AJAX requests, however the page needs to be displayable offline. I also have the constraint, that the image content needs to be stored in a variable and cannot be saved as an external resource.

Is there any simple way to change the content of a SVG image dynamically?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. As you've seen, SVG `<image>` elements use an `href` attribute to source their content. Setting a `src` attribute (as with HTML's `<img>` elements) will not work.
2. The `href` attribute is in [the XLink namespace](http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink). Even though you never declared the namespace prefix, that's what it is, and so you need to set it as such.

You can do this either via jQuery **demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pXA9P/4/**:

```js
$("image").attr('xlink:href',srcAirline);
```

Or standard DOM **demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pXA9P/5/**:

```js
document.querySelector('image')
  .setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink','href',srcAirline);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I am so happy you gave me such a simple solution!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **D3 library** then you can use following to load svg image dynamically.

```
d3.select("body") //select body in html
.append("svg")  //add svg element in body tag
.append("image")  // add image tag in svg element
.attr('xlink:href',"image.svg") //set href property of image element..
.attr("width",50) //set width of image
.attr("height",50) //set height of image
```

This can be very useful for those who are using D3 library.