# how to modify xlink:href with jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

I was trying to follow this question but it's not quite working for me

[Load src content to SVG image dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961120/load-src-content-to-svg-image-dynamically)

I created some code on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sLXCr/

Basically, I am trying (but neither seem to work)...is it a selector issue?

```
$('.graphlink').attr('xlink:href', "#");
document.querySelector('.graphlink').setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', "#");
```

This is the minimized version of my code and I am trying to select all of the class="graphlink" as I want to change all the a href stuff to # and then I also after that want to register an onclick handler to all of those a ref that pops up the same modal for all of them(the modal is static information is all).

hmmmmm, I should mention I am using D3 and maybe there is a way to do it with that in that I want to add a class style but I have optional code that runs on some pages and not others to change all the href...maybe that is possible with D3 code instead?

My latest try with D3 didn't work :(

```
var refs = d3.selectAll('a');
refs.attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return "#"; });
```

I do see the above grabbing 24 a links but it's grabbing links I don't want but 'a.graphlink' seem to select nothing :(

thanks,
Dean

Comment: Your jsfiddle seems to be missing some libraries, but `d3.selectAll(".graphlink").attr('xlink:href', "#");` works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

grrrr, it had nothing to do with that code and everything to do with not posting the whole set of code(which had too much in it I thought)....turns out my code was not in the callback method so it was run toooo soon.