# How to append text in Namespace svg path dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

##   I have to append text in a path inside svg(svg Namespace).I need to do
      it 
    dynamically so i wrote all as javascript function.It is possible to
    append text using  inside text tag but i need to append it 
    dynamically in a Namespace created svg.Following is
    the sample code which i tried. This include a path with an arrow 
    attaching to it, and i need to append text data to this path.Some one 
    please help me.
    http://jsfiddle.net/2ygz14rv/1/  ##

```
var NS="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"; 
var SVG=function(h,w){ // fun create SVG
var svg=document.createElementNS(NS,"svg");
svg.width=w;
svg.height=h; 
createMarkerDef(svg);
return svg;
}
var arrow= function(){                   // fun for arrow 
var arrowObj=document.createElementNS(NS,"path"); 
arrowObj.setAttributeNS(null, "id", "markerArrow");
arrowObj.setAttributeNS(null, "d","M0,0 L10,5 L0,10 L1,5" );
      return arrowObj;
    }

var svg=SVG(500,500);
document.body.appendChild(svg);
var lines= function(mx,my,lx,ly){        // lines
newpath=document.createElementNS(NS,"path");  
newpath.setAttributeNS(null, "id", "MyPath");  
newpath.setAttributeNS(null,"d",'M'+mx+' '+my+' L'+lx+' '+ly);  
newpath.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke", "black"); 
newpath.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-width",2);   
newpath.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "none");
newpath.setAttributeNS(null,'marker-end','url(#markerArrow1)');

    return newpath;
}
var l=lines(80,140,180,100);
    svg.appendChild(l);  
var weight = text1();
svg.appendChild(weight);  
function createMarkerDef(svg) {
    var defs = document.createElementNS(NS, 'defs');
    var markerObj = document.createElementNS(NS,"marker");
    markerObj.setAttributeNS(null, "id", "markerArrow1");
    markerObj.setAttributeNS(null, "viewBox", "0 0 10 10" );
    markerObj.setAttributeNS(null, "refX", "1");
    markerObj.setAttributeNS(null, "refY", "5");
    markerObj.setAttributeNS(null, "markerWidth", "10" );
    markerObj.setAttributeNS(null, "markerHeight", "10");
    markerObj.setAttributeNS(null, "markerUnits","strokeWidth");
    markerObj.appendChild(arrow());
    defs.appendChild(markerObj);
    svg.appendChild(defs);
  }
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a `<textPath>` where the text follows the "MyPath" path?

Comment: yes, can you give me a solution for this ?

Comment: You've done the hard stuff. What is stopping you from creating the `<text>` and `<textPath>` elements, just as you have done the others?

Comment: Please check this link,   http://jsfiddle.net/2ygz14rv/2/    
I am able to append text but  i don't know to include <textPath> inside this text function .

Comment: You just need to create a `<textPath>` element and `appendChild()` it to the `<text>` element. Just the same way as you append the `<text>` element to the `<svg>`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2ygz14rv/4/ .  I tried but its not working .

Comment: Read the errors in your browser console (press F12). You still have three things wrong. Two of the errors are obvious, and for the other, this link will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11961497/1292848