# Why does shift+click open up new tab in firefox for D3 images but not HTML images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

I have an example of my code here :

http://jsfiddle.net/rxzyLsbg/

The image on the left is created in simple html image tag :

```
<img src="http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2014/4/11/1397210130748/Spring-Lamb.-Image-shot-2-011.jpg" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42">
```

The one on the right made with d3 :

```
<svg id="svg"  /> </svg>

d3.select("#svg").append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", "http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2014/4/11/1397210130748/Spring-Lamb.-Image-shot-2-011.jpg")
    .attr("x", -12)
    .attr("y", -12)
    .attr("width", 50)
    .attr("height", 50)
    ;
```

When opening this in `Firefox` and shift+clicking on the images the HTML tag doesn't open in a new tab however the one created in D3 does.

Is there a reason for this ?

I asked another question about this and the code here was suppose to help but doesnt with the D3 :

```
jQuery(document).keydown(function(e){
  if(e.which === 16) {
      console.log('keydown');
      e.preventDefault();
    return;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because check second below. It has href link so it will in new tab.

```
<image href="http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2014/4/11/1397210130748/Spring-Lamb.-Image-shot-2-011.jpg" x="-12" y="-12" width="50" height="50"/>
```

Where as first image contains source(src) link of image.

```
<img width="42" height="42" alt="Smiley face" src="http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2014/4/11/1397210130748/Spring-Lamb.-Image-shot-2-011.jpg">
```

So it will not open in new tab.

Comment: btw do you know how to append an image that doesnt include 'href'. like before i did .attr("xlink:href", "the image link"). how do i do it for src instead of href for example

Comment: Sorry i don't  know much about svg.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961120/load-src-content-to-svg-image-dynamically

Comment: no worries, really appreciate the answer though. Thanks